# musqldb-python doesnt really update the original database

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection, mysql-python

I used mysqldb to connect to a database in my localhost.

It works, but if I add data to a table in the database when the program is running, it shows that it has been added, but when I check the table from localhost, it hasn't been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your table uses innodb engine, you should call `connection.commit()` on every `cursor.execute()`.